# Tensorflow not using GPU

Tags: gpu, tensorflow

I'm trying to run the example seq2seq by Tensorflow, but it won't use the GPU. Here are the step I took to install Tensorflow on a Linux system with Tesla K20x

```
git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow
./configure # Yes GPU
bazel build -c opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/cc:tutorials_example_trainer
bazel-bin/tensorflow/cc/tutorials_example_trainer --use_gpu # The GPU is being used)
bazel build -c opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package /tmp/tensorflow_pkg
pip install /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

After all of this step, I have tensorflow installed. I then try to run the seq2seq example, by

```
bazel run -c opt //tutorials/models/rnn/translate:translate
```

but it will not use the GPU. I then try the example

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow/cc/tutorials_example_trainer --use_gpu
```

and it gives an error

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow/cc/tutorials_example_trainer: error while loading shared libraries: /path/to/home/.cache/bazel/_bazel_hduong/9e8a6e75473e7bf5c9d1c8a084e2a0e9/tensorflow/bazel-out/local_linux-opt/bin/tensorflow/cc/../../_solib_local/_U_S_Sthird_Uparty_Sgpus_Scuda_Ccudart___Uthird_Uparty_Sgpus_Scuda_Slib64/libcudart.so.7.0: file too short
```

Was wondering if anyone know what might cause the program to not use the GPU? Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: you would need to run ./configure inside tensorflow folder. Then you can mention your cuda driver's path and don't forget to mention the cuda compatibility version.

Answer (score 5):

The issue looks to be that when you `bazel run` the translation example, it rebuilds without GPU support. Try adding `--config=cuda` to the `bazel run` command, as follows:

```
$ bazel run -c opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/models/rnn/translate:translate
```

Without this option, Bazel will recompile the entire TensorFlow runtime without GPU support, and use this version when it runs the example application.

Answer (score 1):

it occurs since the cuda is not properly linked. Enter the following command in the terminal

`sudo ldconfig /usr/local/cuda/lib64`

Answer (score 1):

I’m guessing you should install it with a GPU version

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu
```